# Making the height of parent equal to one of its children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that the pink '`#images-wrap`' has the same `height` as the main image. Whenever there are too many small rollover images on the right, it pushes the `height` of the pink `div` to exceed the main image. If I could get it to match it's height instead, then I could use `overflow hidden` to not display the excess rollover images underneath and use overflow as scroll-y so the can scroll down to see the excess small images.

Displaying as a table doesn't work - you'd think a simple child `div` and hidden overflows would do the trick, but you can't as you can't set the height, otherwise the image aspect ratios wouldn't resize. The images must keep their `3:2 aspect ratios`.

The javascript in this solution doesn't work as presumably it cannot fetch the image's height. I've also tried to fetch the height of the child image and this also failed.

Does anyone know of a magic trick that can achieve this?

Really appreciate any help here, thanks!

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  max-height: 150px;
}

#details-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

#main-image {
  width: 80.5%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
}

#main-image>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

#image-thumbs {
  width: 17.5%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  /* make it only scroll when exceeds height of main image */
  /* max-height: 400px;  make this the height of #main-image */
}

.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
}

.image-thumb:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.image-thumb>img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id="main-image" style="background-image: url('http://elephant-family.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_77217466.jpg')">
    <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/" id="main-image-sizer">
  </div>
  <div id="image-thumbs">
    
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <script>
      // hides overflow scroll if less than 5 thumbs
      var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('image-thumb');
      var thumbsWrap = document.getElementById('image-thumbs');
      if (thumbs.length < 5) {
        thumbsWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      // makes '#image-thumbs' not exceed the height of '#main-image'
      var mainImgHeight = document.getElementById('main-image-sizer').style.height;
      var imageThumbsInitialHeight = document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height;
      if (imageThumbsInitialHeight > mainImgHeight) {
        document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height = mainImgHeight;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the main container:

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

#details-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

#main-image {
  width: 80.5%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
}

#main-image>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

#image-thumbs {
  width: 17.5%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  /* make it only scroll when exceeds height of main image */
  /* max-height: 400px;  make this the height of #main-image */
}

.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
}

.image-thumb:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.image-thumb>img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id="main-image" style="background-image: url('http://elephant-family.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_77217466.jpg')">
    <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/" id="main-image-sizer">
  </div>
  <div id="image-thumbs">
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      <img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
    </div>
    <script>
      // hides overflow scroll if less than 5 thumbs
      var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('image-thumb');
      var thumbsWrap = document.getElementById('image-thumbs');
      if (thumbs.length < 5) {
        thumbsWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      // makes '#image-thumbs' not exceed the height of '#main-image'
      var mainImgHeight = document.getElementById('main-image-sizer').style.height;
      var imageThumbsInitialHeight = document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height;
      if (imageThumbsInitialHeight > mainImgHeight) {
        document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height = mainImgHeight;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that looks great! But is there any way of keeping the main image's aspect ratio? I noticed your flex solution just stretches the height rather than making the image-thumbs div the size of its parent

Comment: I think you have to use background image for the main image and set the background-size to cover or something to fix the stretch issue.

Comment: ok thanks, but is there a way to hide the overflow-y scrollbar if there are fewer rolllover images when it's not needed? eg https://jsfiddle.net/etkx2cjr/

Comment: the javascript code I've inserted now doesn't seem to work

Comment: Regarding the overflow, you can set the value to `auto` instead of `scroll`.

Comment: The JS code seems to work to me. Check your console for errors. Also on the `mainImgHeight` variable you should target the element with `main-image` id instead of `'main-image-sizer`, and you should remove the image inside that div because you now have a background image.

Comment: thanks! I used overflow-y auto and that solved it - but whenever you open the full width view and shrink the browser window, it adjusts the height of the scroll rather than adjusting the height of the image and therefore loses its aspect ratio. Is there any way of solving this tricky one?